# Change image opacity when using GetElementById

Tags: javascript, image, opacity, getelementbyid

Part of my Uni module requires me to make a webstory that uses random elements to mix up the story. I'm using GetElementById in JS to embed one random image from an array into a div, which works perfectly fine. The image becomes the background of the div, and I then have text on top of the image - again this all works perfectly fine.

However the issue is that I want the image to be slightly transparent so that the text is easier to read, however no matter what solution I try, I can't get it to work.

I've tried making the div transparent in both CSS and JS, however then the whole div including the text is effected which defeats the point. Then when I try the RGBA style in CSS, the image isn't effected.

So what I need is the image that is loaded into the div through JS to be slightly transparent, whilst the text that is also in the div in the HTML doument to remain untouched.

This is the JS I'm using to randomly select an image:

```js
function randomGun() {
  var imgCount = 3;
  var dir = 'img/';
  var randomCount = Math.round(Math.random() * (imgCount - 1)) + 1;
  var images = new Array
  images[1] = "gun1.jpg",
    images[2] = "gun2.jpg",
    images[3] = "gun3.jpg",
    document.getElementById("left").style.backgroundImage = "url(" + dir + images[randomCount] + ")";
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="left">
    <a id="message">Drive a bit closer to see if anybody is there.</a> 
  </div>

  <script>
    window.onload = randomGun()
  </script>

</div>
```

Comment: Hello, and welcome to StackOverflow. One of the requirements here is that you provide a sample of the code you're having issues with so we can take a look at it more closely. Please edit your answer to add in the code you've written because it'd be hard to help you otherwise.

Comment: read about [mcve]

Comment: I've added some sample code, hope that helps

Comment: I created a snippet for you. It shows the JS in invalid - you need to change `var images = new Array
  images[1] = "gun1.jpg",
    images[2] = "gun2.jpg",
    images[3] = "gun3.jpg",` to `var images = [
  images[1] = "gun1.jpg",
    images[2] = "gun2.jpg",
    images[3] = "gun3.jpg"]` - note the lack of comma and the use of `[]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a nested div with semi-transparent white background.

```
<div id="container">
 <div id="left">
   <div id="nested" style="width:100%;height:100%; background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.5)">
    <a id="message">Drive a bit closer to see if anybody is there.</a>  
   </div>
 </div>

 <script>window.onload = randomGun()</script> 

</div>
```

In addition, I would set everything relative to style in a stylesheet, or at least inside a `<style></style>`.

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE**

Added your JS and fixed it a little. Note the adjustment to the random expression.

---

Perhaps this'll help you.

- Use an element that'll contain 2 other elements, give the container `position:relative` and `z-index:-2`
- Then the 2 elements inside should have `position:absolute`.
- Next give the top element `z-index:-1`, `background:url(http://image-host.com/path/to/img.jpg)`, and `opacity:.5`
- Then the second element should have text and whatever else you want visible. Give this element `z-index:1`.

The reason why opacity wasn't working the way you expected to work is because `opacity` applies to everything within the element as well. Here in the Snippet, we layered an element with content and an element with a background image separately.

**REFERENCE:** https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index

**SNIPPET**

```js
function randomBG() {
    var imgCount = 3;
    var path = 'http://imgh.us/';
    var randomCount = Math.round(Math.random() * (imgCount));
    var images = ['solar_system.jpg', 'kowloon.jpg', 'transparent-map.png'];
  
  document.getElementById("fader").style.backgroundImage = "url(" + path + images[randomCount] + ")";
}

window.onload = randomBG;
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  font: 400 16px/1.5 Verdana;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}
#base {
  position: relative;
  z-index: -2;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}
#content {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 75%;
  height: auto;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: none;
}
#fader {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  min-width: 75%;
  min-height: 75%;
  /*background: url(http://imgh.us/Lenna.png);*/
  opacity: .5;
}
```

```html
<main id='base'>
  <section id='fader'></section>
  <article id='content'>
    <h1>This is the Text</h1>
  </article>
</main>
```

Comment: Valentin's answer seemed to work so I'll leave it at that for now. However I will refer back to this in the future if I get stuck. I appreciate your time for explaining it for me, thank you!

Comment: No problem, if you prefer Mr. C's answer, then click the green ✔ at his post. Happy coding.